# Reducing spacing in nav bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following this tutorial on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial-handling-complex-designs/).

The demo for the tutorial is [here](http://www.zetiz.com/sitepoint/).

I am stuck on this particular code (I changed it a bit to play around):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="mysidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                 <li class="nav-header">What we are?</li>
                 <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Our Clients</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-header">Our Friend</li>
                 <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Yahoo!</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Bing</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Microsoft</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Gadgetic World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
          .....
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two problems:

- How do I reduce the vertical spacing between the text in the sidebar? Reducing the `margin-bottom` on `<ul>` doesn't do anything.
- How do I reduce the horizontal spacing for the sidebar? Right now if you hover over "Google", you'll see the highlight stretch a long ways over to the right. If the horizontal spacing is reduced, will the other `<div class='span8'>` on the same div row compensate for the extra room?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that by "vertical spacing" you mean the space between the bottom of your navigation and the top of "Meet Our Clients". If that's the case, then the answer is "not really". Recall that your navigation is in a row and the height of the row is determined by the tallest thing in that row. which happens to be the text in your second column there.

So your only real solutions to taking up the room in your side bar are:

1. Shorten your text the right hand column
2. Add something below your navigation to fill that space

You *could* jam the contents of that second row into the first (put "meet our clients" below the nav and then the other two in a row (each with span6) after the content currently in the second column, but its going to look horrible. So don't do it.

You second question is a matter of the grid. You have things setup so that your navigation takes up 1/3 of the space and your content takes up 2/3. So unless you like having really **really** long navigation you are going to end up with all that space.

So simply change the widths. Change `span4` to either `span3` or `span2` and then `span8` to `span9` or `span10` respectively. All that matters is that the sum of the span values for the immediate children of a row add up to 12 (4+8, 3+9, etc).

If you do that (I think 2 and 10 will probably work best you'll find that your first problem is greatly reduced because you now have more width for that text and so its going to take up less vertical space, which means you end up with less space (if any) below the navigation.

**UPDATE**

I figured it would be worth throwing up an example. http://jsfiddle.net/littlefyr/y9cTJ All I did was set the span values to `span2` and `span10`

Comment: Sorry, by 'vertical spacing' I meant the spacing in between "Our Friend", "Google", "Yahoo!". "Google" and "Yahoo!" should be more compact because they are listed together under "Our Friend". But the spacing between "Our Friend" and "Google" should be more spacious because it is separating title and a list item. How would I do this?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. @InivisibleBacon is right. the `line-height` controls the veritical spacing, but you are right about the horizontal stuff.

Comment: The line height is intentional. There is a cohesive vertical rhythm to typography. Just changing the line height of the navigation items is going to cause you to loose the rhythm. You could find the styles specific to the navigation and add it there if necessary. However, rather than editing specific styles, you would probably be better off (and get a better result) if you simply customize the look and feel http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables. Under typography you'll find baseLineHeight which you can change and then everything will balance accordingly.

Comment: But, to be honest, I think you're better off leaving the whitespace in there. There is a temptation to "tighten things up" but giving things breathing room, especially important things like navigation, typically serves you better in the long run. But that's just my $0.02

Answer (score 2):

The height of each item is defined by the li declaration.

Change:

```
li {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

in bootstrap.css to something smaller.

The width of the menu is determined by the .span4 rule in bootstrap.css:

```
.span4 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Make that smaller and all the sub-items will follow.